# How to search contact using phone number in AgileCRM?

Tags: rest, api, crm, agile-crm

I am trying to use REST API of AgileCRM, I can search contact using email address but when I'm trying to search contact using phone number I'm not successful.

I have tried and successful :

```
$contact = curl_wrap("contacts/search/email/max@gmail.com", null, "GET", NULL);
```

I have tried and unsuccessful:

```
$contact = curl_wrap("contacts/search/phone/8888888888", null, "GET", NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually

```
$contact = curl_wrap("contacts/search/phonenumber/8888888888", null, "GET", NULL);
```

[From documentation](https://github.com/agilecrm/rest-api#120-get-contact-by-phone-number)